# Complex builds in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio, build

I have a few things that I cannot find a good way to perform in Visual Studio:

1. Pre-build step invokes a code generator that generates some source files which are later compiled. This can be solved to a limited extent by adding blank files to the project (which are later replaced with real generated files), but it does not work if I don't know names and/or the number of auto-generated source files. I can easily solve it in `GNU make` using `$(wildcard generated/*.c)`. How can I do something similar with Visual Studio?
2. Can I prevent pre-build/post-build event running if the files do not need to be modified (`"make"` behaviour)? The current workaround is to write a wrapper script that will check timestamps for me, which works, but is a bit clunky.
3. What is a good way to locate external libraries and headers installed outside of VS? In *nix case, they would normally be installed in the system paths, or located with `autoconf`. I suppose I can specify paths with user-defined macros in project settings, but where is a good place to put these macros so they can be easily found and adjusted?

Just to be clear, I am aware that better Windows build systems exist (`CMake`, `SCons`), but they usually generate VS project files themselves, and I need to integrate this project into existing VS build system, so it is desirable that I have just plain VS project files, not generated ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If you need make behavior and are used to it, you can create [visual studio makefile projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txcwa2xx(VS.80).aspx) and include them in your project.
2. If you want less clunky, you can write visual studio [macros](http://visualstudiohacks.com/articles/general/customize-your-project-build-process/) and custom build events and tie them to specific build callbacks / hooks.
3. You can try something like [workspacewhiz](http://workspacewhiz.com/SolutionBuildEnvironmentReadme.html) which will let you setup environment variables for your project, in a file format that can be checked in. Then users can alter them locally.

Comment: As for point 3. the `.vsprops` files introduced starting with VS2005 are the better option.

Answer (score 4):

I've gone through this exact problem and I did get it working using Custom Build Rules.

But it was always a pain and worked poorly.  I abandoned visual studio and went with a Makefile system using cygwin.  Much better now.

cl.exe is the name of the VS compiler.

Update: I recently switched to using cmake, which comes with its own problems, and cmake can generate a visual studio solution.  This seems to work well.

Answer (score 2):

Specifically for #3, I use property pages to designate 3rd party library location settings (include paths, link paths, etc.). You can use User Macros from a parent or higher level property sheet to designate the starting point for the libraries themselves (if they are in a common root location), and then define individual sheets for each library using the base path macro. It's not automatic, but it is easy to maintain, and every developer can have a different root directory if necessary (it is in our environment).

One downside of this approach is that the include paths constructed this way are not included in the search paths for Visual Studio (unless you duplicate the definitions in the Projects and Directories settings for VS). I spoke to some MS people at PDC08 about getting this fixed for VS2010, and improving the interface in general, but no solid promises from them.

Answer (score 1):

**(1)**. I don't know a simple answer to this, but there are workarounds:

1a. If content of generated files does not clash (i.e. there is no common static identifiers etc.), you can add to the project a single file, such as AllGeneratedFiles.c, and modify your generator to append a #include "generated/file.c" to this file when it produces generated/file.c.

1b. Or you can create a separate makefile-based project for generated files and build them using nmake.

**(2)**. Use a custom build rule instead of post-build event. You can add a custom build rule by right-clicking on the project name in the Solution Explorer and selecting Custom Build Rules.

**(3)**. There is no standard way of doing this; it has to be defined on a per-project basis. One approach is to use environment variables to locate external dependencies. You can then use those environment variables in project properties. Add a readme.txt describing required tools and libraries and corresponding environment variables which the user has to set, and it should be easy enough for anyone to set up.

Comment: Answer 3. is wrong. Since VS2005 one can use `.vsprops` files to do this exact thing in the scope of your project without external help. I've been using them extensively ever since and have used unchanged projects with only a few relevant parameters adjusted in the "property sheet" (`.vsprops`) file. I realize this answer is old, but VS2005 and 2008 were released at the time and thus there *was* a standard way of doing it.

Comment: @0xC0000022L I don't agree that it's wrong. Sure, you can use propsheets. However, it's not a system-wide standard. You'll have to develop your own convention of describing all the libraries via a hierarchy of propsheets, and consistently enforce it. Conceptually, it's no different from the environment variables approach suggested in (3), and it has a disadvantage of locking you into specific build system.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on exactly what you are trying to do, you can sometimes have some luck with using a custom build step and setting your dependencies properly.  It may be helpful to put all the generated code into its own project and then have your main project depend on it.